# Can't find `C/C++: gcc build and debug active file`, when trying to compile C program in vscode classic on manajro

Tags: configuration, compiling, visual-studio-code

When I click the arrow button:
[image]
I get these options:
[image]
I'm looking to get the `C/C++: gcc build and debug active file` option.
This is a freshly installed manjaro and vscode.
Vscode was installed via snap, and the classic version was installed.

This is the output from `gcc --version`:

gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230201
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

And here it is in vscodes terminal:
[image]

Oh and I do have the C/C++ extension pack:
[image]

The output from `snap info --verbose code`:

```
summary: Code editing. Redefined.
health:
  status:  unknown
  message: health has not been set
publisher: Visual Studio Code (vscode✓)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/code
contact:   https://twitter.com/code
links:
  contact:
    - https://twitter.com/code
  website:
    - https://code.visualstudio.com/
license: unset
description: |
  Visual Studio Code is a new choice of tool that combines the
  simplicity of a code editor with what developers need for the core
  edit-build-debug cycle.
commands:
  - code
  - code.url-handler
notes:               
  private:           false
  confinement:       classic
  devmode:           false
  jailmode:          false
  trymode:           false
  enabled:           true
  broken:            false
  ignore-validation: false
snap-id:      Ht0aUHi7ofh9Fbwh6m7jUN2pAy6kzBiu
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 10:49 CET
channels:
  latest/stable:    5e805b79 2023-03-09 (121) 250MB classic
  latest/candidate: ↑                               
  latest/beta:      ↑                               
  latest/edge:      ↑                               
installed:          5e805b79            (121) 250MB classic
```

My c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x86",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-Wall"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: can that snap see the programs installed on your machine, or is it strictly isolating?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure how to test that

Comment: I added the output from snap info code to the questions since its too long to put in a comment. The command says it's not isolated.

Comment: cool! sorry, I was absent. I would have asked whether you where able to run `gcc --version` from within the console in VSCode or just outside.

Comment: Hmm, I got the same output as in the non-integrated terminal, I added an image to the question

Comment: that's very good! so, what does your C++ configuration (Ctrl+Shift+p,  type in the beginning of "C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI), click on it) say about your tool chains?

Comment: By tool chain do you mean standard? If so c = c99, c++ = c++14, I use intellisense mode linux-gcc-x86, and this is my compiler path: /usr/bin/gcc. Sorry im not sure what a tool chain is.

Comment: Note that i have changed my c standard from c17 to c99 and my compiler path from a clang path to the gcc path.

Comment: no, I don't mean standard; I mean which compilers you selected in that settings dialog (or the corresponding JSON config)

Comment: I'll add the JSON file to the question, I think I've selected gcc? but I'm not sure